# Load custom position of page when create viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got a problem with viewpager fragment.

Example: i got an array: 1-2-3-4-5-6.
I want when i create viewpager fragment, it will jump to fragment position 3.

Now the way viewpager do is: load all the list seriated like (1 and 2 and 3 and..), after that this set viewpager.setCurrentItem(3,false).

But with the way like that, it take more time when user click to open viewpager, is any way to do like:

When create viewpager, it will load fragment with position 3 first, after finish build UI of fragment(3), it will load another position of fragment, so when user click to open viewpager, they will not have waiting for viewpager create.

So please give me the ideal for that case.